# How to restrict windows short keys in web application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, windows

I have a requirement to restrict windows short keys, like winodws, alt, tab, alt+tab in web application.

I want to implement the same in one eLearning exam website.

Comment: first of all you can not restrict `winodws` button

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried and exactly what isn't working about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).keydown(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Or, you might want to set something special

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       alert('you press enter');
   }
});
```

[keycode 1](http://keycode.info)

[keycode 2](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)